# Custom Delegate Becomes nil At the time of Calling Method

Tags: ios, objective-c

What I want is that when I add new data to database the table view which I used should be automatically reloaded.

My table view is in MasterViewController. UserDetailUI contains form to stores data in database.

Here is my Code::

MasterViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DBManager.h"
#import "UserDetailsUi.h"

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,ReloadDataDelegate>
{
    UserDetailsUi *userDetail;
    DBManager *db;
    NSMutableArray *firstName;
    NSMutableArray *lastName;
    NSMutableArray *profileData;
    NSMutableArray *rowId;
}
```

MasterViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

self.tableView.delegate=self;
self.tableView.dataSource=self;

// Conferming Delegate
userDetail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserDetails"];
// here i got the reference of UserDetailUI
userDetail.delegate=self;
// here i got the reference of masterviewController in delegate property.


    db = [DBManager getSharedDatabase];
NSString *createTableQuery = @"create table if not exists USER_MASTER (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE, FirstName TEXT, LastName TEXT, ProfilePic TEXT)";
    [db createTable:createTableQuery];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;


    [self downloadDataFromDatabase];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)downloadDataFromDatabase{
    NSString *selectQuery = @"select * from USER_MASTER";
    NSDictionary *data = [db retriveAllData:selectQuery];
    int numberOfRows = data.count;
    NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[data allKeys]];

    firstName = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    lastName = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    profileData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    rowId = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int counter; counter<numberOfRows; counter++) {
        NSDictionary *currentRow = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[data objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:counter]]];
        [firstName addObject:[currentRow objectForKey:@"firstname"]];
        [lastName addObject:[currentRow objectForKey:@"lastname"]];
        [profileData addObject:[currentRow objectForKey:@"ProfilePicture"]];
        [rowId addObject:[currentRow objectForKey:@"RowId"]];
    }
}
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"AddDetails" sender:nil];
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDate *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}
-(void)reloadTableData{
    // This is my delegate method
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

UserDetailsUi.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DBManager.h"

@protocol ReloadDataDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void)reloadTableData;
@end
@interface UserDetailsUi :   UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>{
    UIImagePickerController *imageChooser;
    __weak IBOutlet UIImageView *Profile_Pic;
    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *lnameTf;
    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *firstNameTf;
}
- (IBAction)addDetailsClicked:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<ReloadDataDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

UserDetailsUi.m

```
#import "UserDetailsUi.h"

@implementation UserDetailsUi
    - (IBAction)addDetailsClicked:(id)sender {

    DBManager *db = [DBManager getSharedDatabase];
    NSString *profileEncoded = [self encodeToBase64String:Profile_Pic.image];
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO USER_MASTER (FirstName,LastName,ProfilePic) values ('%@','%@','%@');",firstNameTf.text,lnameTf.text,profileEncoded];
    [db insert:query];

    // delegate method call to reload table view

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    // at the time of execution this delegate object remains nil 
    [_delegate reloadTableData];
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the _delegate in the UserDetailsUi object? It should be an instance of the `MasterViewController` I suppose.

Comment: Yes i set the instance of masterviewcontroller.

Comment: In masterViewController.m File i written userDetail.delegate=self; this statement so userDetail.delegate will have a reference of masterviewcontroller...

Comment: I believe that you are popping yourself, then doing more stuff. You should swap `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` and `[_delegate reloadTableData];`.

Comment: I tried that too but still the delegate remains nil at [_delegate reloadTableData];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the delegate in prepareForSegue instead of viewDidLoad. The instance of the detail controller that you're creating in viewDidLoad is not the same instance that's created by the segue, which is why your delegate is nil.

Comment: You are creating a new userDetail (0xa4cf290) which is not the one created by the segue (0xb15cc30).

Answer (score 0):

use `prepareForSegue()` method which will not be nil

instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier() will creates new Instance of view controller and you need to use existing one ... So `prepareForSegue()` is preferable to delegate

Comment: I made a segue from MasterViewController To UserDetailUI. So i can transfer data from MasterViewController To UserDetailUI but i want that when i press add button Of UserDetailUi Page Tableview of masterviewcontroller should be refreshed... i think for that i can not use this method because there is no segue from UserDetailUi to MasterViewController